# Attempting to restore SQL Server 2005 database to a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance gives reason: 15105 error

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2005, restore, errors

I have a SQL Server 2005 database I am attempting to restore a SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 machine using this statement:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [Db] 
FROM  DISK = N'C:\temp\sql\DB.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'DB' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\NewDB.mdf',  
MOVE N'DB_Log' TO N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\NewDB.ldf',  
REPLACE,  STATS = 10
GO
```

But It keeps giving this error.

> Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The operating system returned the error '5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\NewDB.mdf'.
>   Msg 3156, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   File 'Db' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\NewDB.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>   Msg 3634, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The operating system returned the error '5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation' on 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\NewDB.ldf'.
>   Msg 3156, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   File 'Db_Log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\NewDB.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
>   Msg 3119, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

I am logged into SQL Server as SA. I have Admin permissions on the system.

I have also tried to remove the restore location to another path (that has full permission) with the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it appears my SQL Server installation was mucked up. Running a repair on it produced the following output.

> Setup has detected a non canonical discretionary access control list (DACL) on directory MSAS10_50.MSSQLSERVER.

Which is not the folder I was restoring to, but I assume something temporary was needing to be written.

Resetting the ACL on the folder corrected the restore issue. For good measure I reinstalled SQL Server as I feel uncertain as to the stability of the install.

After this process the original restore database command for the SQL Server 2005 database is now working successfully.

Comment: "MSAS10_50" is the directory for Analysis Services.

Comment: And that isn't the directory you were trying to restore to anyway...

Comment: Both valid comments, I assume I still don't know root cause, although as mentioned, resetting the folder permissions on that folder allowed for the restore to work. Even though it was not where I was restoring too...

Answer (score 4):

"MSSQL.1" is not the directory for a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

You should verify the directory you are trying to place the database in.  The default data path for a normal installation is: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLServer\MSSQL\Data".

**Edit**

If this is indeed the path of the databases for your SQL Server 2008 R2 instance then you can verify this by running the following query:

```
SELECT name, physical_name
FROM sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = 1
```

You should get results similar to this, highlighted the path for my instance:
[image]

You can also verify this path through the restore prompt in SSMS, clicking on the "files":
[image]
However also noting that the error message  `operating system returned the error '5`, the 5 normally indicates permissions issue with the service account running the database engine. If the full message was provided you would see something like

> The operating system returned the error '5(Access is denied)' while attempting 'RestoreContainer::ValidateTargetForCreation'

Comment: I agree its not the normal, it was the way it was setup But the folder does indeed exist and other mdf's live there.  I have also attempted to restore to an alternative path C:\Data\ (which also exists) and same error.

Comment: So if you right click on the server name in SSMS, what path does it give you for the root directory

Comment: name physical_name
master C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf
mastlog C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2, you can find the patches here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2527041

Was your backup created in SQL Server 2005 and you are trying to restore it to SQL Server 2008 R2 (without SP1/SP2)?

In some cases I have noticed that if you take a backup from SQL Server 2005 and try to restore it into SQL Server 2008 it will fail if you don't have SP1/SP2 installed (though I'm not sure why)...

Comment: Why patch it..?

Comment: @Tod, Nope its still giving the original error even after applying the SP2.